# Abrir Janela atrás da janela principal

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esse código que ele faz quase isso.
O único problema é que eu o usuário precisa clicar em um link para que a janela principal fique na frente.
Eu quero que ao abrir a Janela ela automaticamente já fique atrás da janela principal.

Esse é o código que abre a Janela.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.name = "parent";
    $('#link').click(function (event){ 
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open('filho.php', 'fullscreen=yes', 'scrollbars=auto');
    });
});
</script>



<body>
        <a id="link" href="/">Open Window </a>
</body>
```

Esse é o código que volta para pagina ao clicar no link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#link').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(window.opener.location);
            var goBack = window.open('', 'parent');
            goBack.focus();

    });
    });//]]> 

    </script>


    <body>

        <a id="link" href="#">Return to Parent </a>

    </body>
```

LINK DO CÓDIGO FUNCIONANDO: http://pontodosjogos.com/testegrana.php

Comment: já pensou em usar Modais para isso? é esteticamente melhor e mais usual, link caso tenha interesse: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: O meu caso eu precisava abrir o conteudo em uma janela. @Bia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente o que você pretende não é possível. O IE permite que você faça isso, mas os outros navegadores (Chrome e Firefox, por exemplo) bloqueiam esse tipo de ação sem que aja ação direta por parte do usuário (como clicar no link).

Answer (score 0):

como você está usando  **jquery** ... utilize **jquery-ui**, muito facil de implementar
Exemplo [jquery-ui docs](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```